Computing mIoU during validation
I am working on a binary segmentation task and have implemented the following training and validation loop.
I need help with two points:
How can I compute the IoU for each class after every epoch and print the Class 1 IoU, Class 2 IoU, and the overall mIoU score?
Is it better to save the model based on the best mIoU score or the lowest validation loss?
Here is my code:
# Initialize lists to store loss values
train_losses = []
val_losses = []

# Training and validation loop
for epoch in range(n_eps):
    model.train()
    train_loss = 0.0

    # Training loop
    for images, masks in tqdm(train_loader):
        images, masks = images.to(device), masks.to(device)
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(images)
        loss = criterion(outputs, masks)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        train_loss += loss.item()

    avg_train_loss = train_loss / len(train_loader)
    train_losses.append(avg_train_loss)
    print(f"Epoch [{epoch+1}/{n_eps}], Train Loss: {avg_train_loss:.4f}")

    model.eval()
    val_loss = 0.0

    # Validation loop
    with torch.no_grad():
        for images, masks in val_loader:
            images, masks = images.to(device), masks.to(device)
            outputs = model(images)
            val_loss += criterion(outputs, masks).item()

    avg_val_loss = val_loss / len(val_loader)
    val_losses.append(avg_val_loss)
    print(f"Epoch [{epoch+1}/{n_eps}], Val Loss: {avg_val_loss:.4f}")

